# pam_krb5: Error Guessing Name of Local Host Principal

Tags: linux, pam-krb

When trying to log into a new box setup with pam_krb auth I get the following:

```
error guessing name of local host principal
TGTR failed verification using keytab: Hostname cannot be canonicalized
```

This sounds like a DNS verification error of some sort.. Assuming I am on the right track, does anyone know more specifically what it is failing to resolve (client, server, or auth server hostname, PTR lookup)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a DNS A record and PTR record for the server that was showing this error resolved the issue.

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/krb5-latest/krb5-1.10.1/doc/krb5-admin.html#Getting-DNS-Information-Correct

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, add

```
[appdefaults]
  validate = false
```

to /etc/krb5.conf
(credit: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/183923-rhel5-6-issues-ldap-krb5-authentication.html#post877263)